# I have gcc installed in /usr/local/bin why linux can't find it

Tags: linux, gcc

I have gcc installed in /usr/local/bin

```
[root@iz2 usr]# ls /usr/local/bin | grep gcc
gcc
gcc-ar
gcc-nm
gcc-ranlib
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-7.3.0
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-nm
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
```

And there is no gcc in /usr/bin

```
[root@iz2 usr]# ls /usr/bin | grep gcc
[root@iz2 usr]#
```

My $PATH like this

```
[root@iz2 usr]# $PATH
-bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin: No such file or directory
```

when I run commond `gcc --version`, my linux can't find it, why?

```
[root@iz2 usr]# gcc --version
-bash: /usr/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
```

why linux just search `/usr/bin` directory and ignore the `/usr/local/bin` directory which has gcc?

Comment: What is returned by `type gcc` ?

Comment: And `file /usr/local/bin/gcc`?

Comment: Show the output of `ls -al /usr/local/bin/gcc*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have not restarted your bash shell since deinstalling `/usr/bin/gcc` and installing `/usr/local/bin/gcc`, so it still has an outdated command cache.  You can flush the cache using `hash -r`, or you can just log out and log in again.